# Irreducibility of the residual p-adic representation attached to an elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Serre of the irreducibility of the residual representation of an elliptic curve (Frey curve) $E$ when $p \geq 5$ as follows;

Suppose it is reducible. Then $E$ contains a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational (invariant under the action of the absolute Galois group $G$) subgroup $X$ of order $p$. Since $E$ is semistable, the action of $G$ is either via the trivial character or via the cyclotomic character. There are $4$ $\mathbb{Q}$-points of order $2$ (the roots of the right hand side of the equation of $E$ and the point at infinity). In the trivial character case the point that generates $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-point of order $p$, which is a contradiction since now there is $4p$ many $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points contradicting Mazur's torsion theorem. In the cyclotomic character case the curve $E' = E/X$ has a point of order $p$ that is fixed by $G$. This follows from the fact that $G$ acts on the quotient space $E/X$ and by the Weil pairing there is a point that is fixed by $G$. How to finish this? Is the $G$ action of $E/X$ same as in the corresponding elliptic curve?

Comment: I am struggling a lot to follow. What are your assumptions? What exactly do you want to prove? (e.g. suddenly $E$ is semistable, then it has full $2$-torsion over $\mathbb{Q}$, ....).

Comment: Yes, it is a Frey curve.

Comment: @Mikko Pitkonen: Please edit the question so that it does not involve us having to guess what curve you are talking about.

Comment: The proof is given in Proposition 4.3.i) in Saito's book on Fermat's Last Theorem. In the second case, the elliptic curve $E'$ has a point of order $p$ because the kernel of the dual isogeny is the Cartier dual of the kernel of the isogeny to $E'$ and hence a trivial Galois module. Now $E'$ has a point of order $2p$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and Mazur's theorem gives $p<5$. (Not sure what the problem was, but I hope this helps. Walking away wouldn't.)